# How to draw freehand on TPaintBox (or any other control)?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to make a signature pad with Delphi 10.3 FMX. My understanding is that I should handle the `OnMouseMove` event, first setting coordinate in the `OnMouseDown` event, and then use the `DrawLine()` method.

So far I managed this:

```
unit HeaderFooterFormwithNavigation;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.TabControl,
  System.Actions, FMX.ActnList, FMX.Objects, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit;

type
  THeaderFooterwithNavigation = class(TForm)
    ActionList1: TActionList;
    PreviousTabAction1: TPreviousTabAction;
    TitleAction: TControlAction;
    NextTabAction1: TNextTabAction;
    TopToolBar: TToolBar;
    btnBack: TSpeedButton;
    ToolBarLabel: TLabel;
    btnNext: TSpeedButton;
    TabControl1: TTabControl;
    TabItem1: TTabItem;
    TabItem2: TTabItem;
    BottomToolBar: TToolBar;
    pb1: TPaintBox;
    edt1: TEdit;
    edt2: TEdit;
    edt3: TEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TitleActionUpdate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure pb1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
    procedure pb1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  HeaderFooterwithNavigation: THeaderFooterwithNavigation;
  _lastPoint: TPointF;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.LgXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}
{$R *.iPhone4in.fmx IOS}

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.TitleActionUpdate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender is TCustomAction then
  begin
    if TabControl1.ActiveTab <> nil then
      TCustomAction(Sender).Text := TabControl1.ActiveTab.Text
    else
      TCustomAction(Sender).Text := '';
  end;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { This defines the default active tab at runtime }
  TabControl1.First(TTabTransition.None);
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = vkHardwareBack) and (TabControl1.TabIndex <> 0) then
  begin
    TabControl1.First;
    Key := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.pb1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  _lastPoint.X := X;
  _lastPoint.Y := Y;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.pb1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
var
  thisPoint: TPointF;
  brush: TStrokeBrush;
begin
  if pb1.Canvas.BeginScene then
  try
    pb1.Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 2;
    pb1.Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
    pb1.Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;

    thisPoint.X := X;
    thisPoint.Y := Y;
    pb1.Canvas.DrawLine(_lastPoint, thisPoint, 1);
    _lastPoint := thisPoint;
  finally
    pb1.Canvas.EndScene;
  end;

end;

end.
```

When I run it on my mobile (Android) and press on its screen, the whole screen becomes black. Why is that? How can I make simple freehand drawing app?

Comment: You shouldn't draw on a TPaintBox outside of the paintbox onPaint event because the Canvas may not be set up correctly. Move your drawing code to the onPaint event (begin / end scene not needed) and then call pb1.Paint from the MouseMove event. This is my guess as to the cause of the problem. Alternatively you could use a TImage and draw to the image's bitmap canvas, which can be done anywhere.

Comment: thanks, I will try that

Comment: The other reason that TImage is needed is because TPaintBox doesn't store an image, so everything will be lost when it needs to repaint. You could use an off screen bitmap but that's equivalent to just using TImage. TPaintBox uses less memory but should only be used if drawing reletively few objects. You could store a list of polylines and draw them in the TPaintBox OnPaint event but that would quickly become slow after many lines have been drawn.

Answer (score 2):

I've listened to Xylem's advice and switched to TImage control like this:

```
unit HeaderFooterFormwithNavigation;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.TabControl,
  System.Actions, FMX.ActnList, FMX.Objects, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit;

type
  THeaderFooterwithNavigation = class(TForm)
    ActionList1: TActionList;
    PreviousTabAction1: TPreviousTabAction;
    TitleAction: TControlAction;
    NextTabAction1: TNextTabAction;
    TopToolBar: TToolBar;
    btnBack: TSpeedButton;
    ToolBarLabel: TLabel;
    btnNext: TSpeedButton;
    TabControl1: TTabControl;
    TabItem1: TTabItem;
    TabItem2: TTabItem;
    BottomToolBar: TToolBar;
    img1: TImage;
    btnClear: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TitleActionUpdate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure img1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
    procedure img1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
    procedure img1Tap(Sender: TObject; const Point: TPointF);
    procedure img1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
    procedure btnClearClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  HeaderFooterwithNavigation: THeaderFooterwithNavigation;
  _lastPoint: TPointF;
  _down: Boolean;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.LgXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}
{$R *.iPhone4in.fmx IOS}

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.TitleActionUpdate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender is TCustomAction then
  begin
    if TabControl1.ActiveTab <> nil then
      TCustomAction(Sender).Text := TabControl1.ActiveTab.Text
    else
      TCustomAction(Sender).Text := '';
  end;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.btnClearClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  img1.Bitmap.Clear(TAlphaColorRec.White);
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { This defines the default active tab at runtime }
  img1.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create(round(img1.Width), round(img1.Height));
  img1.Bitmap.Clear(TAlphaColorRec.White);
  TabControl1.First(TTabTransition.None);
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = vkHardwareBack) and (TabControl1.TabIndex <> 0) then
  begin
    TabControl1.First;
    Key := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.img1MouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  _lastPoint.X := X;
  _lastPoint.Y := Y;
  _down:=True;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.img1MouseMove(Sender: TObject;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
  var
  thisPoint: TPointF;
begin
  if _down then
  begin
  thisPoint.X := X;
  thisPoint.Y := Y;
  with img1.Bitmap.Canvas do
  begin
    BeginScene;
    Stroke.Thickness := 5;
    Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
    Stroke.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
    DrawLine(_lastPoint, thisPoint, 1);
    EndScene;
  end;

  _lastPoint := thisPoint;
  end;

end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.img1MouseUp(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  _down:=false;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.img1Tap(Sender: TObject;
  const Point: TPointF);
begin
  _down:=True;
  _lastPoint := Point;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Looks good. My only comment would be to use if BeginScene and try finally to make sure that EndScene always gets called, like you did in your original code.